# Use data.table::fread to read text file

Tags: r, csv, data.table

The data like this when I use function `readLines`.

[image]

I can use `readLines` to get data like this, how can I do this in `data.table::fread`.

```
train <- fread("./data/train_first.csv", encoding = 'UTF-8', quote="", fill=TRUE)
```

This is error:

```
Error in fread("./data/train_first.csv", encoding = "UTF-8", fill = TRUE) : 
  Expecting 3 cols, but line 99771 contains text after processing all cols. Try again with fill=TRUE. Another reason could be that fread's logic in distinguishing one or more fields having embedded sep=',' and/or (unescaped) '\n' characters within unbalanced unescaped quotes has failed. If quote='' doesn't help, please file an issue to figure out if the logic could be improved.
```

Comment: you seem to have 3 headers but 6 fields in each line

Comment: how can i deal with it in data.table?

Comment: it depends on why you have that, are those fields 6 real fields?

Comment: chinese is comment,just has 3 columns. that is `id , disscuss(chinese) , score`

Comment: then it should probably be put in between quotes prior to the import. Or you can try to work on the readLines object. I don't think it is possible to directly tell `fread` how to make the difference between a field-separator comma and a chinese-comment-separator comma :-/

Comment: ok,thank you for your answer~

Comment: is there always the same number of commas inside the chinese comments?